# PlayerPrefs not saving unlocked levels

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I used this code to try and make buttons in my level select screen not interactable if the level has not been completed. By default, I want to set level one's button to be unlocked so I used this:

```
    [SerializeField] Button[] levelBUttons;

    private void Start()
    {
        int levelCurrentlyAt = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levelCurrentlyAt", 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < levelBUttons.Length; i++)
        {
            if(i+2 > levelCurrentlyAt)
            {
                levelBUttons[i].interactable = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is when I press play, level one's button is also not interactable
The reason I have set the int to 2 and not 1 is that in the build settings the scene order is 1) Start Screen, 2) Level Select Screen 3) Level One.
In the inspector, level one's button is also the first button element in the button array.

I changed the for loop to this and it seems to work:

```
        int levelAt = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levelAt", 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < levelBUttons.Length; i++)
        {
            if(i+1>levelAt)
            {
                levelBUttons[i].interactable = false;
            }
        }
```

But is this not wrong because level one has a build index of 2 and 1, I am supposed to use i+1 and not i+2.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your question, but you might be getting confused on the order. The first scene in build order will have index of 0, as that's how indexing in most languages works. Thus level 1 will have index of 1, unless you have 2 scenes before it in the build menu. Hope I could help!

Comment: I have do have 2 scenes before my Level One scene thats why I am confused as to why the first piece of code does not work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).